# Nativescript-Vue devtools Not updating The Page

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

When I navigate from one page to another, the devtools from Vue js in nativescript-vue simply does not update.

It only shows the current page, and not the following where I navigate. [image]

As you can see in the image, it stacks on UserCreation and I am navigating to VerifyCode Page.

I am using nativescript-vue

Answer (score 0):

You can force a refresh in devtools with the refresh icon.

I have improved this in the [`v2.5.0-alpha.0`](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/releases/tag/v2.5.0-alpha.0) version, please try the latest alpha ([`v2.5.0-alpha.3`](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/releases/tag/v2.5.0-alpha.3) at the time of writing) and see if it improves the developer experience for you.

Comment: Yes its fine. Thank you.